# How to get youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json with Google API?

Tags: python, json, youtube-api

I'm trying to work with Google API with python, so I took an example code from the site and at some point, those lines appears :

```
 # Trusted testers can download this discovery document from the developers page
 # and it should be in the same directory with the code.
 with open("youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json", "r") as f:
    doc = f.read()
    return build_from_document(doc,http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
```

Do you know how I could find this youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json ? It's written that I can download it from the developers page, but I really can't find where.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find the contents here: [`youtube-v3-discoverydocument.json`](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest)

Additionally, you can use [this reference](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/getRest) to retrieve similar data for any other Google API.  For example, to retrieve the data you are looking for, set the parameters `api` and `version` to "youtube" and "v3", and click "Execute".